# ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt not found in BIN folder

Tags: jmeter-5.0

I have not been able to see the ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt file in the bin folder. I am running jmeter 5.2.1. I need to sort this so I can be able to add certificated to my API calls to the server. Please any help or pointing me to the right direction would be a life saver.

Or if anyone has an easier way I can attach certificates to each call to the server that might also work. I am running out of options. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

JMeter by default out of the box doesn't come with this certificate in any of the versions until you actually start recording. In case you have migrated from a different machine/environment I would suggest below in the box where you are not able to see the certificate.

Add a Test Script Recorder, select Target controller to itself and click on Start. Once you start the recording and the pop-up for the certificate appears, refresh bin directory and you will be able to see the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I run this file and then ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt appear in bin folder (apache-jmeter-5.5 version)

apache-jmeter-5.5\apache-jmeter-5.5\extras\proxycert.cmd

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Hey here's what I did on my Mac to solve this

1. Go to the Mac terminal and run this command

   sudo find / -name 'ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt' 2>/dev/null
2. Wait a little as this command takes a while
3. Once you've received the paths in the terminal, go to one of them.
4. Once you've opened the path and you've seen the certification go back to Firefox and click on import certification again.
5. Drag the certification from its folder onto the popup folder from Firefox and open it from there.
6. Now try to run.