# Unable to find ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt on Jmeter installed on Mac

Tags: jmeter

I installed Jmeter on my mac using brew. I did setup my Jmeter for script recording and started scripting recording. I got a popup saying:

> Root CA certificate ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA created in JMeter bin directory
> You can install it following instructions in *Component Reference* documentation
> See *Installing the JMeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording* paragraph.

[image]

But when I looked into the Jmeter directory /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.3/bin/ and
/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.3/libexec/bin/, I could not find the ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.
Am I looking at right place or am I missing any step?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76617557/15446248
this is a s olution i found while going through this issue on mac.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [jmeter formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/jmeter.rb) it should be under `$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/Cellar/jmeter/$YOUR_JMETER_VERSION_HERE/libexec/bin/`, the file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt`.

Where [`$HOMEBREW_PREFIX` is the environment variable](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/what-does-prefix-mean-in-this-statement/787), if it's not defined you can check it using `brew --prefix` command.

And last but not the least you can search your hard drive(s) for the certificate using [find](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_find_help.php) command like:

```
find / -type f -name ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt
```

it will print the location(s) of all the file(s) matching this name which are present in your filesystem

By the way there is an alternative way of recording a JMeter test - [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates, just follow your test scenario in the browser and you will be able to export the recording in form of JMeter .jmx script